# Which repository should I download Redis (windows version) from?

Tags: windows, redis

I recently found two GitHub repositories for Redis (windows version). First, I installed the one by MicrosoftArchive, but then I found one with a higher version number and later release date by tporadowski.

Now, I'm not too sure which I should install or if they're different in any way. I would love some guidance with this!

These are the two repositories:

- https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases
- https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the Microsoft github, that project has been abandoned. They mention Memurai as a derived project.
Although closed source, Memurai offers a free developer edition.
Check it out.